# C# OpenTK mouse picking incorrect?

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

This is my code of generate a ray

```
float x = (2.0f * e.X) / Width - 1f;
float y = (1.0f - (2.0f * e.Y) / Height);
float z = 1.0f;
Vector3 ray_nds = new Vector3(x, y, z);
Vector4 ray_clip = new Vector4(ray_nds.X, ray_nds.Y, -1.0f, 1.0f);
Vector4 ray_eye = Matrix4.Invert(Projection) * ray_clip;
ray_eye = new Vector4(ray_eye.X, ray_eye.Y, -1.0f, 0.0f);
Vector3 ray_wor = (Matrix4.Invert(View) * ray_eye).Xyz;
ray_wor = Vector3.Normalize(ray_wor);

ray.Origin = CameraPosition;
ray.Direction = ray_wor;
```

And I draw the ray into the scene.
When I look at -Z axis, it working perfect like this (I click plane center)
[image]

But when my camera front is not -Z axis or +Z axis
ray's direction was incorect like this (I click plane center)
[image]

I have no idea what's wrong with it for a week
Can anyone help me ?
If you need other info of my code, please tell me, thank you :)

**Update 1:**

This is my view :

```
public Matrix4 View { get => Matrix4.LookAt(CameraPosition, CameraPosition + CameraFront, CameraUp); }
```

and this is my rotate code :
(rotate the scene is change camera position and look to view center actually)

```
lookX += (lastMouseLoc.X - e.X) * RotateSensitive;
lookY += (e.Y - lastMouseLoc.Y) * RotateSensitive;
lookY = Math.Max(lookY, -MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(89));
lookY = Math.Min(lookY, MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(89));
Vector3 v = new Vector3((float)Math.Sin(lookX) * (float)Math.Cos(lookY), (float)Math.Sin(lookY), (float)Math.Cos(lookX) * (float)Math.Cos(lookY));

CameraPosition = ViewCenter + v * lastDistOfCenter;
CameraFront = Vector3.Normalize(ViewCenter - CameraPosition);

lastMouseLoc = e.Location;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the z-coordinate after converting from the normalized device space to the viewing space:

<s>`ray_eye = new Vector4(ray_eye.X, ray_eye.Y, -1.0f, 0.0f);`</s>

```cs
ray_eye = new Vector4(ray_eye.X, ray_eye.Y, ray_eye.Z, 0.0f);
```

Comment: I try ray_eye.Z and look at -Z axis, then click the plane center, but the ray's direction's Y goes very low (ray_row is (0, -0.932718, -0.3606065)) and not shoot the target correctly

Comment: I updated my post for more information and I think maybe my CameraUp was incorrect that it should be update with lookX and lookY